# Firefox plugin for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, html

Is there a plugin for IE to run firefox engine available? just opposite to what IE Tabs does.

Comment: Curious why you would want to do that.

Comment: @Rob one reason is to enable support for new HTML and CSS features in an old browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been technically possible for a long time, there was some work done a while ago by Adam Lock to [wrap the Gecko engine as an ActiveX control](http://lxnews.org/2011/04/11/mozilla-kills-gecko-embedding/).  If installed you could then access a Gecko renderer using the `object` tag in the same way you might add a Flash or Java applet, however it's not been updated for a while.

However, [Mozilla recently announced that they're stopping support for ActiveX emdedding](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.embedding/c_NMcO-N8wo/discussion) because it's too hard to maintain for too little reward and will hold back the implementation of a full multi-process model for Gecko.

Answer (score 1):

No, but there is Chrome Frame which renders using Chrome.

http://www.google.com/chromeframe